# setting rightbarbuttonitem in navigation item to nil doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, view, uinavigationbar

I have an object with the class FSDDropdownPicker (a dropdown menu) and I want to edit one of the entries in my dropdown menu. Upon doing so I change the object to nil, and the right bar button item to nil yet the old dropdown menu remains even after instantiating the new dropdown and adding it to the right bar button item.

```
    if(_picker){
//        _picker.tableView.delegate = nil;
//        _picker.tableView.dataSource = nil;
//        _picker.delegate = nil;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
//        [_picker removeFromSuperview];
//        _picker.view
    }

    _picker =  [self.navigationItem addDropdownPickerWithOptions:[arr copy]];
    _picker.delegate = self;
```

I also have functionality such that if the menu becomes empty then I erase the dropdown completely and just do

```
if([api.myGroups count]==0){
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    return;
}
```

However my rightBarButtonItem remains unchanged. Added Notes: I'm also using AMSlideMenu if that makes a difference but it really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after re-adding new picker, the `FSDDropdownPicker` keeps the old `tableView` still in the view hierarchy, so try calling `[_picker removeFromSuperview];` before adding a new one.

Also there's no need to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` and *nil* the delegates and data source. Seems you just have to assign it again.

Additionally, the line `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _picker;` is redundant as the category method `addDropdownPickerWithOptions:` on `navigationItem` already assigns the newly created picker to `navigationItem`.

EDIT: My bad, you need to call this code before creating new picker:

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.superview.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the library doesn't take care of this by itself, so you either do it this way or create a pull request with a fix for the `FSDDropdownPicker` library.

EDIT EDIT:
If you're not using CocoaPods, you could try to put the table view and `options` definition in the header file - not a nice solution, but probably the easiest for you now. Move this 
`@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;` and this `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *options;` line to `FSDDropdownPicker.h` and you won't have to create new picker instance every time you want to add/delete an item. Just add/delete an item to options and reload the table view.

Comment: [_picker removeFromSuperview] doesn't work since there's no method associated with it. _picker.view doesn't exist either. I knew the the last statements were redundant but it was mostly because I was annoyed it wasn't refreshing. But I'll take them out, it's not helping either. It seems after simply reassigning it, it takes an actual 30ish seconds to add another new right bar button item. I hadn't noticed before because I was too impatient, just like any other user would be. Any idea why it takes so long? I've updated my code above.

Comment: It still takes 30+ seconds for me to see the change in view. I'm using a custom image per element and I'm not noticing a change in either the functionality of the menu nor the image until 30 seconds have past. Do you think it may be a problem with my simulator?

Comment: If I were in your situation, I'd use different lib (e.g. [LMDropdownView](https://github.com/lminhtm/LMDropdownView/blob/master/LMDropdownView/LMDropdownView.h)) or code the functionality myself.

Or try one more ugly fix - see my new EDIT

Comment: I've already made the tableview a publicly accessible attribute. should I do the [tableview beginediting] and stuff? I think I could do that and change the table view, but it wouldn't help my case for changing the image that is currently displayed.

Comment: or did you just want me to call remove from superview directly at the tableview? I think I might just switch though, is LMDropdownView capable of being dynamic?

Comment: Yes you can try calling `removeFromSuperview` on the table view. Or switch to a different lib - with `LMDropdownView` you would have to implement a table view by yourself which would give you more control though.

Comment: I'm switching to a different library haha, that's the only correct answer for this insanely static library...